# unable to retrieve the Table th tag value using webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

From the below html i want to check each row in the table header value and if matched need retrieve the td value

below is my html

```
<table class="span-5" id="summaryTable" title="Table showing Summary data">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="width-40" id="num">
<a href=" " aria-label=" " title="" class="ui-link">(12) App no</a>:
</th>
<td headers="num">
<a href=" " aria-label=" " title=" " class="ui-link">(11)</a> 
<strong>2796179</strong>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="noLines alignLeft width35" id="EnglishTitle"> 
<a href=" " aria-label=" " title=" " class="ui-link">(54) English Title</a>:
</th>
<td class="noLines alignLeft width65" headers="EnglishTitle">
FRAME BIT-SIZE ALLOCATION
</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

i want to collect the each th tag value (i.e `(12) App no` `(54) English Title`)

my java code

```
WebElement summary = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody"));
                List<WebElement>rows = summary.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
                for (int i=1;i<=rows.size();i++){

                    String dc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td/th/a")).getText();
                    if (dc.equalsIgnoreCase("(12) App no")){
                         appNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/td/strong")).getText();
                    }                       
                }
```

but i'm getting no such element: Unable to locate element: `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody/tr[1]/td/th/a"}`

Comment: so your objective to find the row number or get row as `WebElement ` when data matched ?

Comment: Objective is if matched the Th value will extract the corresponding row td value

Comment: I have added an answer for this. please use it and let me know your feedback

Comment: A `th` directly inside a `td` doesn't make sense and it's not what is in your HTML. Remove the `td/` part and use: `//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody/tr["+i+"]/th/a`

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code for this

```
 WebElement  elem = driver.findElement(By.id("summaryTable"));

    List<WebElement> lists = elem.findElements(By.tagName("th"));

    for(WebElement el : lists){

        WebElement element = el.findElement(By.tagName("a"));

        String  str = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
        System.out.println(str);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making it a bit complicated, can you try bit simpler version?

```
public String getRequiredDataFromTableFromRow(String header){
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("summaryTable"));
    List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
    for (WebElement row:rows) {
        if(row.getText().contains(header)){
           return row.findElement(By.tagName("td")).getText();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are also arrays within the row, so you need to specify the position to get the text. The `th` tag is not there within the `td` tag.

Try the following code:

```
WebElement summary = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody"));
List<WebElement>rows = summary.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

for(int i = 1; i <= rows.size(); i++) {

    String dc = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/th[0]")).getText();

    if(dc.equalsIgnoreCase("(12) App no")) {
        appNo = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='summaryTable']/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[0]")).getText();
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Below is basically for getting you the text for each "th" element.

  > ```
  > WebElement summary = driver.findElement(By.id("summaryTable"));
  > List<WebElement>rows = summary.findElements(By.tagName("th"));
  > for(WebElement row : rows){
  > row.getText();
  > }}
  > ```

In the above code, I am getting the reference using the "id" and using same object reference in order to get the elements list for "th" tag.

In case you want to perform operation on the text been found can be done using the reference of the row element